# How to approximate electron electron interactions in helium Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

So I know that using the helium Hamiltonian

[image]

has no analytic solution in the SE. I'm wondering how one goes about approximating the solution.

Comment: "Quantum Mechanics of One- and Two-Electron Atoms", by Hans Bethe and Edwin Salpeter, first published in 1957 and still readily available on Amazon or other book sellers.

Comment: Several approximation techniques are discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom